# react native socket.io-client doesn't connected to https server on Release build

Tags: react-native, https, socket.io, release

**react native info**

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
    Memory: 8.28 GB / 15.85 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.14.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    npm: 6.13.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: ^0.61.5 => 0.61.5
```

**socket.io-client version**

```
"socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
```

**my code**

```
const EVENT_SERVER = 'https://my.prod.server';

socketInstance = SocketIOClient(EVENT_SERVER, {
    forceNew: false,
    transports: ['websocket'],
    reconnection: true,
  });
```

**Question**

If I build `debug mode` connect to my `https` server. but `release mode` cannot be connect to my `https` server.

what can I do? Give me some advice..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem !

The problem is `console.dir()`function `console.dir()`function is not support to release mode.